# Scala: a method with a parameteric or generic type argument that returns a Future

Tags: scala, future

My title is probably not describing the problem piece of code I am trying to understand:

Here is the piece of code:

```
def getMeConcurrentInputStream[A, I <: InputStream](in:I)(fn:I => A):Future[A] = {
    future {
      fn(in)
    }andThen {
      case all => in.close()
    }
  }
```

I am trying to understand what to make of this function. What is this:

```
[A, I <: InputStream](in:I)(fn:I => A)
```

and what is this: `(in:I)(fn:I => A)`

and the function is returning a Future? How would I interpret: `Future[A]`

How do I interpret all of the above?  And how would I use this function by invoking it from someplace else in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def getMeConcurrentInputStream
```

function named `getMeConcurrentInputStream`

```
[A, I <: InputStream]
```

that with generic type `A` and a type `I` which is `InputStream` or a subclass of it.

```
(in:I)(fn:I => A)
```

with a parameter list of an `I` and a parameter list of a function accepting `I` and returning `A`

```
:Future[A] = {
```

returning a `Future` of type `A`

```
future {
```

which creates a `Future` in the in-scope implicit `ExecutionContext`

```
fn(in)
```

and the future calls the function `fn` with argument `in`.

```
}andThen {
```

and afterwords, whether successful or a failure,

```
case all =>
```

in all cases

```
in.close()
```

call `.close()` on `in`.

---

This function wraps some operation involving an `InputStream` in a `Future` and closes it when it is done.

For example, suppose I wanted to asynchronously read the first byte of a file, and then print it out. I could do this:

```
val fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("example.txt")
val myFuture = getMeConcurrentInputStream(fileInputStream) { inputStream =>
    inputStream.read()
}
myFuture.map(println)
```

Personally, I can't see much use for this function, but there you go.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting in a lot of effort.